# Is there a way to bind udp as a transport layer for jax-ws?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, udp, jax-ws

Hi i'm looking if there is a way to use udp as a one-way webservice call? 
I'm interested particularly in jax-ws reference implementation (metro).

Comment: I'm not sure about Metro, but Apache CXF supports SOAP over UDP.

Comment: Yes thanks @austin I found this too. Also i'm interested in web services discovery which is also available in Apache CXF but not in JAX-WS RI. I'm working on my own project so i could choose cxf but I don't want to. It's learning project and if there is no such solution maby one lesson would be to implement this:) Again thanks for answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: This makes little sense. A web service means using HTTP.  HTTP is not one way; there is a request and a response. It is not designed for use with datagrams.

Comment: @Raedwald: Not true. WSDL services are supposed to work over different transports, not just HTTP. That is what the `binding` part in the service description is for. There is an OASIS standard for [SOAP over UDP](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/soapoverudp/1.1/os/wsdd-soapoverudp-1.1-spec-os.html).

Comment: Sorry for late answer @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen. But as i said for me it is learning project. I thought about multicast one way webservice call. I don't know if it is posible or good solution but i want to get to know webservices more deeply. For what? Let's assume i have webservice application deployed on glassfish cluster. This app manipulate cache, and each webservice should had the same state of cache. So i thought that i could multicast changes to the others by one way call. I know that there is ehcache that do this using jgrups or some other protocols but i want to use webservices:)